# When I run my application on google kubernetes engine, i get org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden error

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using the trial version of the google kubernetes platform to deploy my spring boot application.
I just did a maven install and tried to run my spring boot application. My application actually calls a public rest api at regular intervals and processes the response. It works fine in my local windows system.
But when i run it in the GKE, it gives the below error

````
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR... (919 bytes)]
        at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:186) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:125) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:819) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:777) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6] ```

my http call:
public void callHttpUrl(List<String> pinCodes) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String url = env.getProperty("base.url");
        String date = DateUtil.getTodayDate();
        for (String pinCode : pinCodes) {
            UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(Objects.requireNonNull(url))
                    .queryParam("pincode", pinCode)
                    .queryParam("date", date);
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            headers.add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36");
            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("parameters", headers);
            uriComponentsBuilder.toUriString();
            LOGGER.debug("URL is {}", uriComponentsBuilder.toUriString());
            String response = restTemplate.exchange(uriComponentsBuilder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class).getBody();
            LOGGER.debug(response);
            processResponse(response);
        }
````

Comment: An HTTP 403 response means that the client is not permitted to access the resource.  Does the API you are calling actually require some type of authentication?

Comment: No, it does not require any authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried accessing any other API to see if the issue persists or if it's only with the current API you're having trouble with? It sounds like it's a new configuration but have you had any successful requests to other APIs?